# Postman API Testing for all Software Methods & Functionality

Tags: api, automated-tests, postman, integration-testing

I just started a Developer apprenticeship, and I've been tasked with creating automated integration tests for the company's software using Postman.

I've spent 2.5 weeks trying to learn all about Postman and the software, and I'm still struggling with how to construct these tests.

For example, the software allows you to add an item (with several data fields) into a database. I want to create a test collection that allows me to run requests that create a new entry, update that entry, and delete that entry. I've got a get request (GetItems), a post request (NewItem), an update request (UpdateItem), and a delete request (DeleteItem).

How do I set this up so that the NewItem request creates an id variable that can be used to update and delete in subsequent requests?

So far, the only thing I've gotten to work is hard-coding sample data for each item field into the body of the request. This means I then have to edit that data manually in the update and delete requests, and it only works about half the time I run the requests.

I've researched this for several days now, and can't make heads or tails of how to make Postman do what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas or advice would be amazing, I really want to learn and create useful tests for my new team. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth heading over to community.getpostman.com and asking this question there. This feels like the type of question that will likely get down voted by folks and I would hate for that to discourage you from finding a solution.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. while software questions are sometimes off topic, i can appreciate you asking this question. i would also recommend learning lambda from AWS. It will take some time to learn, but there are tutorials and you can run automated tests to APIs with it. Please post some of the code you have tried. are you working with XML/JSON? do you know if your API is REST? the more info you give on here, the more help you will usually get